# Taking screenshot of only relevant content of webpage | Selenium | Python

Tags: python, selenium, screenshot

How can I take screenshot of only relevant content of any webpage using Selenium and Python?

[I want to take the screenshot of the marked content (specifications) in this photo instead of whole page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlH7p.png)

[Example webpage link](https://www.startech.com.bd/benq-gw2480-fhd-monitor)

Currently I'm taking screenshot of the whole page. Also I want avoid referencing any class or id while taking the screenshot. Please let me know if I can achieve this (if yes, HOW?) or have to change my requirements.  If there is any workaround such as cropping the relevant content, please do share too. Thanks.

Comment: can you confirm the url?

Comment: https://www.startech.com.bd/benq-gw2480-fhd-monitor

Comment: Would be great to share a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you achieved until now with `Selenium`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome appears to be a bit temperamental when screenshotting - only takes what's visible on screen, so I would advise Firefox/geckodriver for these kind of jobs. The following will take a full screenshot of that element:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as Firefox_Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time as t



firefox_options = Firefox_Options()

firefox_options.add_argument("--width=1280")
firefox_options.add_argument("--height=720")
# firefox_options.headless = True

driverService = Service('chromedriver/geckodriver')
browser = webdriver.Firefox(service=driverService, options=firefox_options)
actions = ActionChains(browser)
url = 'https://www.startech.com.bd/benq-gw2480-fhd-monitor'
browser.get(url) 
elem = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//section[@id='specification']")))
elem.screenshot('fullspec.png')

print('screenshotted specs')
```

Comment: Thanks. Any insight regarding avoiding referencing any id or class of that specific element? Any possibility?

Comment: You can try locating it using text content, for example. do you have other websites to screenshot?

Comment: Will try using text content. And, yes, I have to take screenshot from multiple websites, almost same element-wise scenario. I can make things different for each website, but trying to figure out a consistent and dynamic approach. For example, even if the class or id of those element is changed by a website, I still want ti be okay to keep the screenshot thing going for that website. So, that is why trying to get rid of class or id dependency.